Codeigniter 3: Inserting Dynamic Input type = "file" Course>Section>Media Field
<script>
    let mediaHtml = `
    <div class="mediaItem">
        <input type="text" name="sections[${sectionDiv.data('section-id')}][media][${mediaCounter}][media_title]" placeholder="Media Title">
        <input type="file" name="sections[${sectionDiv.data('section-id')}][media][${mediaCounter}][media_name]">
        <button type="button" class="removeMedia">Remove Media</button>
    </div>`;
    mediaDiv.append(mediaHtml);
</script>

I am working on a project where I am uploading media files through a form. Each media file has a corresponding title. I'm using CodeIgniter for this project. I'm facing an issue where I can successfully insert the media_title into the database, but I'm encountering difficulties with inserting the media_name (file name) into the folder where the media files are stored. I'm using dynamic field names for both media_title and media_name, structured as sections[X]media[Y]media_name and sections[X]media[Y]media_title. How can I ensure the title and the file name are correctly inserted and managed?
Initial Controller:

  if (isset($section['media'])) {
    foreach ($section['media'] as $media) {
        $mediaTitle = $media['media_title'];
        $mediaName = $media['media_name'];
        $this->ExamModel->save_lesson($sectionId, $mediaTitle, $mediaName);
    }
}


Solved the problem: Here's the correct code for inserting dynamic input field (file).
UX Scenario:
Users can create courses with multiple sections.
Each section can have various input fields, including file uploads.
if (isset($section['media'])) {
    foreach ($section['media'] as $mediaIndex => $media) {
        $mediaTitle = $media['media_title'];
        
        // Construct the correct file input name
        $fileInputName = "sections[$sectionIndex][media][$mediaIndex][media_name]";
        
        // Access the uploaded file from $_FILES using the correct keys
        if (isset($_FILES['sections']['name'][$sectionIndex]['media'][$mediaIndex]['media_name'])) {
            $mediaName = [
                'name' => $_FILES['sections']['name'][$sectionIndex]['media'][$mediaIndex]['media_name'],
                'type' => $_FILES['sections']['type'][$sectionIndex]['media'][$mediaIndex]['media_name'],
                'tmp_name' => $_FILES['sections']['tmp_name'][$sectionIndex]['media'][$mediaIndex]['media_name'],
                'error' => $_FILES['sections']['error'][$sectionIndex]['media'][$mediaIndex]['media_name'],
                'size' => $_FILES['sections']['size'][$sectionIndex]['media'][$mediaIndex]['media_name']
            ];
            
            echo "<h2>";
            print_r($mediaTitle);
            echo "</h2>";
            // Print the file information
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($mediaName);
            echo "</pre>";

   
            $this->ExamModel->save_media($sectionId, $mediaTitle, $mediaName['name']);
        } else {
            echo "No file uploaded for section: $sectionIndex, media: $mediaIndex";
        }
    }
}

